# C: check if a 3-digit number is palindromic

Tags: c, function, if-statement, palindrome

So I've written a programme that takes a 3-digit number from the user and checks if it's palindromic or not:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int isPalindromic(char q, char w, char e); 
int main()
{
    int res;
    char a,b,c;

    printf("Give me a three digit number\n");
    scanf("%c %c %c", &a, &b, &c);
    res = isPalindromic(a,b,c);

    if (res == 1)
       printf("damn son that's palindromic how u do dat u a haker!!!\n");
    else
        printf("B O O O  L O S E R\n");

    system("pause");
    return 0;   
}

int isPalindromic(char q, char w, char e)
{
   int result;
   if (q == e)               
       result = 1;
    else
        result = 0;
    return result;                     
}
```

Due to lazyness, I thought of taking each digit as a character instead of an integer, and then the isPalindromic function compares the first digit with the third one.

It works like a charm, but does it have any weakness or sth? 
Have I done anything wrong?

Comment: What about if the users enters "zrz" ? do you take this as a palindromic 3-digit number? if not, then your approach is bad.

Comment: Yup, you should check whether the user is really entering a numeric value or any `char`.

Comment: Check the return of `scanf()`.

Comment: @Magix & Haris like this?                                                                         if (a >= '0' && a <= '9' && b >= '0' && b <= '9' && c >= '0' && c <= '9')
    {
     res = isPalindromic(a,b,c);
    
     if (res == 1)
       printf("damn son that's palindromic how u do dat u a haker!!!\n");
     else
        printf("B O O O  L O S E R\n");
     }
    else
        printf("not cool bruh\n");

Comment: [`isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) should be enough for the digit check.

Comment: To take in 3 1-digit numbers, use `int x,y,z; if (scanf("%1d%1d%1d", &x, &y, &z) == 3 && x == z) is_palindromic();`

Answer (score 0):

You could make the program be more general by writing a function that checks if any string of chars is palindrome:

```
int ispal(const char *s)
{
    int start, mid, end;

    mid = strlen(s) / 2;
    end = strlen(s) - 1;

    for (start = 0; start < mid; ++start, --end)
        if (s[start] != s[end])
            return 0;      /* not palindrome */

     if (start == mid)
         return 1;         /* palindrome */
}
```

You could then check if the user input is a 3 digit number(`isdigit` and `strlen`), and only if it is, pass it as input to the `ispal` function. This general approach allows your application to be more extensible in the future.

edit: Don't use `system("pause")`, because not all systems support the `pause` command.